# Can We Run The Flutter Project offline on server instead of using The Internet connection?

Tags: flutter, offline, dart-pub, flutter-packages, pubs

Instead of taking internet connection from the server and run the flutter PROJECT ONLINE ON SERVER  which works fine ,INTENTIONALLY I WANT TO RUN MY FLUTTER PROJECT  OFFINE ON THE SERVER WHICH IS NOT WORKING .

FOR OFFLINE:

I downloaded the packages like http, google-fonts etc..
Created the asset folder and mentioned the path.
Did the pub get which throws error .
Added the path into the pub dev

Answer (score 0):

You need an internet connection to download Gradle dependencies, errors points to no network when trying to download these dependencies.